# How do I verify if data is new?

Tags: algorithm, time

I need to receive some data from xml document from the web and 
display them but only if I didn't output them earlier.

I check xml document every 5 minutes.

Data items don't have any timestamps associated with them. (So I can't compare them)

What is the best way to check if data is new?

Comment: if you show the xml data structure you can get much better answers.

Answer (score 1):

The XML you're reading may not have any timestamps in it, but can you provide a specific example of the web resource you're accessing?

If it is just a resource accessed over regular HTTP, and if the HTTP server is following standards, there should be a `Last-Modified` HTTP Header that you could use to determine when the file was last modified.  (Details at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html.)

Comment: Thanks! I mean in general: 1)i have some document(xml or html)2)i received and displayed existing (at the moment) data items from it.3)i check every 5 min if new data items appeared, if they appeared i display(add them to the displayed earlier) them. The Question is: about 3) - how do i select only new data items?? not previously displayed??